# Cannot get sticky headers to work with SuperSLiM

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, superslim

I am trying to implement sticky headers in my already existing `RecyclerView` which has headers, but not sticky ones. [SuperSLiM](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM) looks promising, but I am not able to integrate the library into my existing code. The example that follows with the source code runs just fine and I have tried adapting to this as well as to follow the steps on the [SuperSLiM wiki](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM/wiki).

My `RecyclerView` is initially empty. The problem I run into is when I first add items to my adapter and call `Adapter.notifyItemChanged()` on these items. After I do this I get thrown into `LayoutManager.onItemsUpdated()`. That method looks like this:

```
public void onItemsUpdated(RecyclerView recyclerView, int positionStart, int itemCount)
{
    super.onItemsUpdated(recyclerView, positionStart, itemCount);
    View first = this.getChildAt(0);                        // null
    View last = this.getChildAt(this.getChildCount() - 1);  // null
    if(positionStart + itemCount > this.getPosition(first)) // NullPointerException
    {
        if(positionStart <= this.getPosition(last))
        {
            this.requestLayout();
        }

    }
}
```

Here, both `first` and `last` becomes `null`, thus a `NullPointerException` is thrown on the line below. Note that `onItemsUpdated()` **is not called in the example app**, so this error does not happen there. I don't know why; `Adapter.notifyItemChanged()` is also called in the example app.

What could be the issue?

**My Fragment class:**

Note that switching back to the normal `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` in the code below makes everything work as it normally does.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment
{
    private MyRecyclerView      mRecyclerView;
    private MyAdapter           mAdapter;

//  private RecyclerView.LayoutManager      mLayoutManager; // Normal RecyclerView.LayoutManager working just fine
    private LayoutManager                   mLayoutManager; // SuperSLiM LayoutManager crashing

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        MyActivity myActivity = (MyActivity) rootView.getContext();

        mRecyclerView = (MyRecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview);

//      mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(myActivity); // Normal RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        mLayoutManager = new LayoutManager(myActivity);       // SuperSLiM LayoutManager
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myActivity);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        myActivity.onShoppingListCreated();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onDataSetChanged()
    {
        if (mAdapter == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // This is called multiple times after a button press at some point.
    // Thereafter, if it is the SuperSLiM LayoutManager that is in play,
    // the error explained above occurs.
    public void onItemChanged(int position)
    {
        if (mAdapter == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

**Stack trace when crashing:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.getPosition(RecyclerView.java:6097)
            at com.tonicartos.superslim.LayoutManager.onItemsUpdated(LayoutManager.java:542)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.dispatchUpdate(RecyclerView.java:665)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$5.onDispatchSecondPass(RecyclerView.java:675)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AdapterHelper.consumeUpdatesInOnePass(AdapterHelper.java:547)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.processAdapterUpdatesAndSetAnimationFlags(RecyclerView.java:2530)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2318)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:875)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1488)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:868)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventRe
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar these days, I used this library: https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview

Its pretty easy if you are used to RecyclerViews adapters.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that library as well. I do not believe I can use it though, as its docs states: *The header views are drawn to a canvas, and are not actually a part of the view hierarchy. As such, they can't have touch states, and you may run into issues if you try to load images into them asynchronously.*. In my case the headers need to have some state and additional views (e.g. a small button) in addition to just plain text. I guess that would not be possible with this library. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @Krøllebølle, you are completely right, indeed I use the same mechanism of timehop in my https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter project, and I am searching help to make sticky headers in the good way with a custom LayoutManager, without huge coding as the project SuperSlim is done (~3400 lines for section and sticky headers only!?)

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the end of **onBindViewHolder** method:

```
 //configuring sticky headers
    final LayoutManager.LayoutParams lp = LayoutManager.LayoutParams.from(holder.itemView.getLayoutParams());
    lp.setSlm(LinearSLM.ID);
    lp.setFirstPosition(getHeaderPosition(position));
    holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

**getHeaderPosition** method returns the header position for each item